# SpringBoot3.1.5 - RequestMappingHandlerMapping Repetition

Tags: java, spring

After migrating to Spring 3.1.5, RequestMapping HandlerMapping occurs repeatedly. I don't think it's a normal situation, can I ask you for your opinion?

Below is the log immediately after API call.

I don't think it's a browser problem because I'm doing it as a postman

I'm not sure why getHandler continues to traverse in log-level debug mode or higher, resulting in a total of 9 logs.

I'm studying individually, but this part bothers me a lot. Please help me ㅜ_ㅠ

```
2023-11-18T01:43:47.678+09:00 DEBUG 89627 --- [p-nio-80-exec-4] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.template.server.domain.member.controller.MemberController#getMemberInfo(Authentication)
2023-11-18T01:43:47.679+09:00 DEBUG 89627 --- [p-nio-80-exec-4] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.template.server.domain.member.controller.MemberController#getMemberInfo(Authentication)
2023-11-18T01:43:47.679+09:00 DEBUG 89627 --- [p-nio-80-exec-4] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.template.server.domain.member.controller.MemberController#getMemberInfo(Authentication)
2023-11-18T01:43:47.679+09:00 DEBUG 89627 --- [p-nio-80-exec-4] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.template.server.domain.member.controller.MemberController#getMemberInfo(Authentication)
2023-11-18T01:43:47.680+09:00 DEBUG 89627 --- [p-nio-80-exec-4] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.template.server.domain.member.controller.MemberController#getMemberInfo(Authentication)
2023-11-18T01:43:47.680+09:00 DEBUG 89627 --- [p-nio-80-exec-4] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.template.server.domain.member.controller.MemberController#getMemberInfo(Authentication)
2023-11-18T01:43:47.680+09:00 DEBUG 89627 --- [p-nio-80-exec-4] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.template.server.domain.member.controller.MemberController#getMemberInfo(Authentication)
2023-11-18T01:43:47.680+09:00 DEBUG 89627 --- [p-nio-80-exec-4] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.template.server.domain.member.controller.MemberController#getMemberInfo(Authentication)
2023-11-18T01:43:47.681+09:00 DEBUG 89627 --- [p-nio-80-exec-4] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.template.server.domain.member.controller.MemberController#getMemberInfo(Authentication)
2023-11-18T01:43:47.681+09:00 DEBUG 89627 --- [p-nio-80-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/api/v1/member/info", parameters={}
2023-11-18T01:43:47.681+09:00 DEBUG 89627 --- [p-nio-80-exec-4] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.template.server.domain.member.controller.MemberController#getMemberInfo(Authentication)
```

Is it a filter problem?